# How to convert current date to epoch timestamp?

Tags: python

How to convert current date to epoch timestamp ?

Format current date:

```
29.08.2011 11:05:02
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

That should do it

```
import time

date_time = '29.08.2011 11:05:02'
pattern = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))
print epoch
```

Comment: since mktime is being used, does that mean you should adjust the returned epoch to UTC?

Comment: Is it the same for python3 ?

Answer (score 23):

Your code will behave strange if 'TZ' is not set properly, e.g. 'UTC' or 'Asia/Kolkata'

So, you need to do below

```
>>> import time, os
>>> d='2014-12-11 00:00:00'
>>> p='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>> epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d,p)))
>>> epoch
1418236200
>>> os.environ['TZ']='UTC'
>>> epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d,p)))
>>> epoch
1418256000
```

Comment: A typo, your code snippet should be: os.environ['TZ']='UTC' . Note that key TZ is adorned with '

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The timezone adjustment is critical.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are using a 24 hour time format:

```
import time;
t = time.mktime(time.strptime("29.08.2011 11:05:02", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import time
def expires():
    '''return a UNIX style timestamp representing 5 minutes from now'''
    return int(time.time()+300)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want UTC try some of the `gm` functions:

```
import time
import calendar

date_time = '29.08.2011 11:05:02'
pattern = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
utc_epoch = calendar.timegm(time.strptime(date_time, pattern))
print utc_epoch
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from time import time
>>> int(time())
1542449530


>>> time()
1542449527.6991141
>>> int(time())
1542449530
>>> str(time()).replace(".","")
'154244967282'
```

But Should it not return ?

```
'15424495276991141'
```

Comment: time.time() returns current seconds after epoch (posix time) as a float, no need to adjust datetime.now().

If you did want to use datetime.now(), it has a `.timestamp` method which returns the same thing.

Comment: You mean like this ?

Comment: I think `int(time())` is exactly the answer to this question.  I can't believe this has no upvotes after 18 months.

Answer (score 4):

**Short-hand** to convert python date/datetime **to Epoch** (without microseconds)

```
int(current_date.strftime("%s")) # 2020-01-14  ---> 1578956400
int(current_datetime.strftime("%s")) # 2020-01-14 16:59:30.251176 -----> 1579017570
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'current_datetime' is not defined`

Comment: current_datetime is your input date, which you want to convert

Answer (score 3):

Use [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse the time, and call [time()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time) on it to get the Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I think this answer needs an update and the solution would go better this way.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime("29.08.2011 11:05:02", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%s")
```

or you may use datetime object and format the time using %s to convert it into epoch time.

Comment: Note: ``%s`` is not supported in windows.